# Specify a certain column in a range?

Tags: vba, excel, range

So sorry if this is really obvious, but I'm having some trouble connecting two pieces of information.

I have a one-cell range (for example, like A1) and a second, larger range (such as A1:C223).  I want to be able to write some code that will make a new range using the column of the one-cell, and the number of rows of the larger range (so in this example, it would end up being A1:A223).

I want to use this specifically to create a loop later, but I'm having trouble creating this range first.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean like this `Range("A1:A" & (Range("A1:C223").Row + Range("A1:C223").Rows.Count-1)).Address`

Comment: Or to make it generic   `Range("A1:A" & (rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count-1)).Address` Where `rng` is your second range

Comment: Thanks for the help Siddharth!  I used the code in the answer below, but I wanted to thank you for taking the time out to help me.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. See if this works:

```
Sub test()
Dim rangeA As Range, rangeB As Range, combRange As Range

Set rangeA = Range("A1")
Set rangeB = Range("A1:C223")

Set combRange = Range(Cells(rangeB.Rows(1).Row, rangeA.Column), _
    Cells(rangeB(rangeB.Rows.Count, 1)(1).Row, rangeA.Column))

Debug.Print combRange.address

End Sub
```

Edit: This is a little too much perhaps, it looks like @SiddharthRout has a great solution too in the comments :D

Comment: FWIW - `rangeB.Rows(1).Row` simplifies to `rangeB.Row` (because it defaults to acting on the first cell in the range), and `rangeB(rangeB.Rows.Count, 1)(1).Row` can be `rangeB.Row + rangeB.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: Thanks for this!  I used the code you put originally but modified it slightly to get the correct range (Range A is A1, Range B is the large range):

`Set comborange = Range(Cells(RangeA.Row, RangeA.Column), Cells(RangeB.Rows.Count, RangeA.Column))`

Again, thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: @ElAsado Be careful with your suggested code - if `rangeA` was `Range("A6")` and `rangeB` is `Range("A3:C12")` then your result will be equivalent to `Range("A6:A10")` - which I don't think is what you want.  Also note that your `Cells(RangeA.Row, RangeA.Column)` can be simplified to `RangeA`.